# Node.js req.user won't be global in res.locals.user

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I try to put my `req.user` value in the global variable for all views with

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user; // this line
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});
```

but nothing works. I have to put it on every `render()` function. What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Define "nothing works." Do you get an exception/error or is `user` an empty object in your view or something else?

Comment: The value is undefined when i put it in res.locals.user

Comment: Does adding `console.dir(req.user);` right before `res.locals.user = req.user;` show an object in the console?

Comment: Nothing, undefined again

Comment: Ok, so then the problem is not with `res.locals`, but is instead with `req.user` not being set before that middleware function.

Comment: But it's set in the render() functions and the value is passed correctly like this: 
    routes.login = function(req, res){
  res.render('auth/login', {
   title: 'Log in',
   user: req.user
  });
 };

Comment: `req.user` won't be set before `app.use(passport..)`..stuff, make sure the order is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think you are using the req.flash correctly resulting in it returning undefined.

You should probably give it a second value.

Take a look at this post and see if you can figure it out: [How to send flash messages in Express 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160743/how-to-send-flash-messages-in-express-4-0)