# Showing a message on res.redirect in Express / Node.Js app

Tags: node.js, express

I currently use `res.error('message');` to show a message on the page that I load using `res.redirect(url);` in my *Express*/*Node.js* app.

*Is there another way of showing a message, if I don't want it to be error message, but something else?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`res.redirect(url)` will actually issue an HTTP 302 redirect which will cause your user's browser to make a brand new request for whatever page is specified by the value in the `url` variable.

If you want to show the user a message after the redirect, you would need to store that message somewhere that will persist between requests and then read it on the subsequent page load. This is often accomplished by storing the message in a cookie or in server-side session state and is often referred to as flash storage.

The `express-flash` [middleware](https://github.com/RGBboy/express-flash) can help you with this, although I'm not 100% certain of its compatibility with Express 4.

You also might find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160743/how-to-send-flash-messages-in-express-4-0) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the other `res` method to send the message:

`send('message')` or `end('message')` seems being the most appropriated.

You could otherwise display some page with `.render (view, templateParam)`.

More details here, on [express request documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#response)

Answer (score 0):

Use flash. They provide templates for error, success and informational messages. Very useful if your users are coming in with web browsers.