# express response locals disappear

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to send error messages back to the client without adding them to the url. Here is my attempt:

```
exports.register = function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.password != req.body.password_repeat) {
        res.locals.err = 'Passwords must match.';
        res.locals.action = 'register';
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
    }
...

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    req.url = '/';
    res.render('index', {
        action: res.locals.action,
        error: res.locals.error,
        redirect: res.locals.redirect
    });
};
```

So the redirect works fine and exports.index executes. The problem is that res.locals are gone by then. Is this because once I redirect it is considered a new req/res cycle? Any way I can pass this information through redirect without doing something like `res.redirect('/?error=error')`

Comment: What you are looking for are flash messages, try this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160743/how-to-send-flash-messages-in-express-4-0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash) package from [expressjs](https://github.com/expressjs), but you need to have `session` middleware to use it. Also, you can use [express-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash) package from [RGBboy](https://github.com/RGBboy) but you need to have both `cookieParser` and `session` middlewares in this case.