# Intercepting flash message

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local, connect-flash

I am using Passport authentication with 'local' strategy for my application. I want the user to be able to know if the username and password entered by user is invalid and if valid then redirect to dashboard. 
This is how i am authenticating the user:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'}), function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
});
```

Redirect part works fine, but the user enters invalid user/pass the flash message in `failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'` dosent show up on the login page.
This is how i handle my login route:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/login', {'title' : 'VoteCenter - Login', message: req.flash('message')});
});
```

What do i need to use in `req.flash('??????')` to intercept the flash mesaage coming from `failureFlash`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send flash messages in Express 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160743/how-to-send-flash-messages-in-express-4-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get message through `req.flash('error')`(default)

also you can pass failureFlash object with your custom message name like it:

```
failureFlash: { type: 'authError', message: 'Invalid username or password.'}
```

then get message `req.flash('authError')`

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for. Worked for me.